# YTPlayer Video Quality in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, ytplayer

I'm looking at a site with a fullscreen video background on the home page. Now I'm using [YTPlayer](https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer/wiki) which pulls in a video from YouTube so they can do all the heavy lifting when it comes to buffering etc.

The problem I'm having is the video quality in Chrome is rubbish until it kicks up to the desired quality after quite a few seconds. It's perfect in IE, Safari and Firefox but the latest Chrome isn't playing ball.

Does anyone know how I can get Chrome to use the set quality from load rather than serving up this lower quality version straight away? (I'm open to other full screen video methods too).

Comment: I'm also having the same problem - please let me know if you receive an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set video quality in YTplayer properties
   Choose hd720, large, medium, or small. For example:

   ```
     ytp.proxy.suggestedQuality = "hd720";
     /* hd270: Sets video quality to 720p* HD video.
      large: Sets video quality to 480p.
      medium: Sets video quality to 320p.
      small: Sets video quality to the 240p.*/
   ```
2. You can change the quality setting in line 47 of the javascript. also add add &hd=1 into line 34.
3. Still problem? jump to any of these plugins.
   a.) http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/
   b.) http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/
   c.) http://my.opera.com/core/blog/2010/03/03/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio-2

Comment: This is an old post, I'm using version 2.7.0 and I have the same problem, as the line #47 and #34 now have changed. Could you help me in this?